# Позиционирование абсолютного элемента изнутри относительного

Tags: css

Задача в том что бы блок внутри другого с относительным позиционированием получая абсолютное мог выходить за рамки родителя. Проблема с поиском ответа в том что все задают один и тот же вопрос: почему это так работает, а мне нужно наоборот от этого избавится.

```css
.mainblock>div {position: relative; width: 500px; background: #000; margin: 0 auto;}
#n-ans {position: absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="mainblock">
<div>
 <div class="content cont-text">
  <form>
   <input type="button" value="Да" id="n-ans">
   <input type="button" value="Нет">
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

`n-ans` нужно перемещать относительно всей страницы, а не блока div с relative.

Comment: _почему это так работает, а мне нужно наоборот от этого избавится_ - как так? и от чего избавиться?

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос.

Comment: _нужно перемещать относительно всей страницы_ - ты имеешь ввиду, чтобы при установки let,top и т.д. координаты считались от всей страницы, а не от родительского блока?

Comment: @Grundy именно это я и имею ввиду.

Comment: тогда это не возможно. Такое поведение описано в спецификации: положение блока абсолют рассчитывается от положения первого родительского блока не статик

Comment: @Grundy Оу... Понял, пойду переписывать структуру.